# aws api-gateway - cdk stage deployment setup - updating without drift

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I want to setup an api gateway using cdk - with `RestApi`, `Resource`, `Method` and [`Stage`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_apigateway/Stage.html) - all included in the cdk stack.

To create the `Stage` construct in the cdk stack, it required a `Deployment`, so I defined this in the cdk stack.

```
deployment = apigateway_v1.Deployment(self, "Deployment", api=rest_api)

stage = apigateway_v1.Stage(
    self, 
    "test",
    deployment=deployment,
    stage_name="test"
)
```

However, when I later make a change to the Resource Method definition - and re-deploy the cdk stack, the api-gateway is not updating.  So I end up either redeploying the api-gateway either via the aws console or the [aws-cli create-deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/create-deployment.html)

But now when I check for cloudformation stack drift, it shows the Stage has drifted.

How can I prevent stack drift while keeping the `Stage` in the cdk stack?

Answer (score 1):

Found some suggestion to add a unique identifier to the deployment construct id from the following links:

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/13134
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66377831/1211547

a disadvantage is the `deployment` will be recreated with every `cdk deploy` even if there are no changes

Comment: This is what worked for me finally .Thanks!